# Creating a list from the word cloud

Tags: string-manipulation, code-request, word-cloud

So, the `WorldCloud` function applied to a string generates a word cloud graphic in which each word is sized according to its multiplicity in the string.
Is there a way by which we can convert that same result in the form of list where each word is listed from the highest multiplicity to lowest multiplicity?

```
WordCloud["All children, except one, grow up. They soon know that \
they will grow up, and the way Wendy knew was this. One day when she \
was two years old she was playing in a garden, and she plucked \
another flower and ran with it to her mother. I suppose she must have \
looked rather delightful, for Mrs. Darling put her hand to her heart \
and cried, \"Oh, why can't you remain like this for ever!\" This was \
all that passed between them on the subject, but henceforth Wendy \
knew that she must grow up. You always know after you are two. Two is \
the beginning of the end."]
(* output will be world cloud graphic here, which we want in the form of a list like below *)
(* {grow, Wendy, know, knew.........} *)
```

Comment: Don't you have a weighted list or a flat list  _before_ you create the WordCloud?

Comment: Are you asking how to sort a weighted list by weight? Or are you asking how to take a flat list and sort its elements by frequency? I.e. is "word clouds" just a red herring here?

Comment: how to take data like `WikipediaData["example"]` which is converted to word cloud by `WordCloud[]`. Instead, I want a list or table ordered by frequency and not the world cloud.

Comment: This question shows no research effort and no minimal example. Consequently, I am casting a close vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the data from `WordCloud`, which strips common words from the input string, here's an internal hack to retrieve that data:

```
Quiet@TextWords[]; (* trigger autoload, if needed *)
Internal`InheritedBlock[{TextWords},
   Unprotect[TextWords];
   DownValues@TextWords = Prepend[
     DownValues@TextWords,
     HoldPattern[TextWords[str_String] /; ! TrueQ[$in]] :> 
      Block[{$in = True},
       Sow[TextWords[str], "TextWords"]]
     ];
   Protect[TextWords];
   Reap[
    cloud = WordCloud[
     "All children, except one, grow up. They soon know that they \
will grow up, and the way Wendy knew was this. One day when she was \
two years old she was playing in a garden, and she plucked another \
flower and ran with it to her mother. I suppose she must have looked \
rather delightful, for Mrs. Darling put her hand to her heart and \
cried, \"Oh, why can't you remain like this for ever!\" This was all \
that passed between them on the subject, but henceforth Wendy knew \
that she must grow up. You always know after you are two. Two is the \
beginning of the end."],
    "TextWords"]
   ] // MapThread[#1[#2] &,
    {{Show[#, ImageSize -> Medium] &, 
      Grid@*ReverseSortBy[{Last, First}]@*Tally@*Flatten},
     #}] & // Row
```

[image]

Note the word cloud just has the strings without the counts.  You can get the `FontSize` from the word cloud, but I don't know how consistently it may be interpreted in terms of counts:

```
Cases[cloud, Style[word_String, fs_, ___] :> {word, fs}, Infinity] // 
  With[{min = Min@Cases[#, Scaled[x_] :> x, Infinity]},
   # /. _[_, Scaled[x_]] :> x/min] &
(*
  {{"grow", 7.},
   {"Wendy", 4.}, {"know", 4.}, {"knew", 4.},
   {"henceforth", 1.}, ..., {"Oh", 1.}}
*)
```

Answer (score 2):

TextWords can be used to extract words from text:

```
TextWords[WikipediaData["example"]] // Short
(* {Example,may,refer,to,<134>>,Barcelona,with,distinctive,architecture} *)
```

Maybe you want just nouns, in which case TextCases is useful:

```
TextCases[WikipediaData["example"], "Noun"] // Short
(* {Example,gratia,example,example,<37>>,stories,sermons,suburb,architecture} *)
```

Once you have the words, you'll proably want to normalize them to avoid undercounting due to capitalization. I'll use ToLowerCase. Then you can use Counts or Tally:

```
Counts[ToLowerCase[TextWords[WikipediaData["example"]]]] // Short
(* <|example->9,may->2,refer->1,to->3,<<93>>,with->1,distinctive->1,architecture->1|> *)

Tally[ToLowerCase[TextWords[WikipediaData["example"]]]] // Short
(* {{example,9},{may,2},{refer,1},<<94>>,{with,1},{distinctive,1},{architecture,1}} *)
```

Then you'll want to sort. The Association can be sorted directly, the tallies will need to sort by Last:

```
Counts[ToLowerCase[TextWords[WikipediaData["example"]]]] // Sort
(* or *)
Tally[ToLowerCase[TextWords[WikipediaData["example"]]]] // SortBy[Last]
```

Now, if you want just the words, not the frequencies, you can extract them:

```
Counts[ToLowerCase[TextWords[WikipediaData["example"]]]] // Sort // Keys
(* or *)
SortBy[Tally[ToLowerCase[TextWords[WikipediaData["example"]]]], Last][[All, 1]]
```

At some point you may want to filter the words (e.g. nouns like I showed with TextCases), but I don't know what criteria you want, and I also don't know the criteria WordCloud uses, so I don't have anything to show.

Comment: Thanks. Because `WordCloud` already does processing for us, I was hoping that there was some way to just take that processed data and carry on from there.

Comment: @grshvetal I suppose one could also take the point of view that because `TextWords` already does the processing for us, one might hope to avoid `WordCloud`. However, there is a difference: `WordCloud` calls `TextWords` after deleting common words, and then processes the output of `TextWords` and returns only the graphics.

Answer (score 1):

> Instead, I want a list or table ordered by frequency and not the
> world cloud

```
text = WikipediaData["example"];
wct = WordCounts[text] // Sort
```

For a column-wise presentation:

```
Normal[wct] // Multicolumn[#, 5] &
```

[image]